# openmp no speed up c++ for-loop function

Tags: c++, for-loop, openmp

i try to use openmp to speed up some very slow code; but no matter how i tried, it did not speed up;

there is my code, its a piece of open source code;

---

```
void wavefrontRegionGrowing(cv::Mat &image)
{

  int proc_num = omp_get_num_procs();
  omp_set_num_threads(proc_num - 1);
  // This function spreads the colored regions of the given map to the neighboring white pixels
  if (image.type() != CV_32SC1)
  {
    std::cout << "Error: wavefrontRegionGrowing: provided image is not of type CV_32SC1." << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  cv::Mat spreading_map = image.clone();
  cv::Mat image_clone = image.clone();

  volatile bool finished = false;
  while (finished == false)
  {
    finished = true;
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) firstprivate(image_clone) shared(finished, spreading_map)
    for (int row = 1; row < spreading_map.rows - 1; ++row)
    {
      auto current_row_ptr = spreading_map.ptr<int>(row);
      for (int column = 1; column < spreading_map.cols - 1; ++column)
      {
        if (current_row_ptr[column] > 65279) // unassigned pixels
        {
          // check 3x3 area around white pixel for fillcolour, if filled Pixel around fill white pixel with that colour
          bool set_value = false;
          for (int row_counter = -1; row_counter <= 1; ++row_counter)
          {
            auto thisimg_counter_row_ptr = image_clone.ptr<int>(row + row_counter);
            for (int column_counter = -1; column_counter <= 1; ++column_counter)
            {
              int value = thisimg_counter_row_ptr[column + column_counter];
              if (value != 0 && value <= 65279)
              {
                current_row_ptr[column] = value;
                set_value = true;
                finished = false; // keep on iterating the wavefront propagation until no more changes occur
                break;
              }
            }
            if (set_value)
            {
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    spreading_map.copyTo(image_clone);
  }
  image = spreading_map;
}
```

Could you please help me with this?  I hope it could get twice the speedup.

Comment: Four nested for loops, is this some Image Processing code?

Comment: @kiner_shah yeah, its part of the [ipa_room_segmentation](https://github.com/ipa320/ipa_coverage_planning) , used to divide the map image into rooms.

Comment: What is the typical while loop count?

Comment: This is too broad I guess. For this, the algorithm behind this code needs to be understood and profiling has to be done on some sample input to understand where it takes too much time (or why omp parallel doesn't work properly). But do remember that only the code which can be parallelized will be parallelized (at least that's what I think).

Comment: @Laci  one of map pimage; while loop count: 1343  ; image row  count:2612 column count :2612

Comment: @kiner_shah i know it is too broad, this problem has bothered me for a long time. i'm not sure if i have some low-level errors in my code

Comment: To speedup your parallel code you have to get rid of `firstprivate(image_clone)` as it is very slow. If I am correct, you only read it in parallel region, so it can be shared. Your parallel region should be before the `while` loop and you should use tasks (e.g. `taskloop`). It may also speed up your code.  From OpenMP point of view you can do this without rewriting your algorithm, but consider @kiner_shah's advice and profile your code for hotspots and redesign your algorithm if necessary.

Comment: This line also can be quite slow `spreading_map.copyTo(image_clone);` consider swapping matrices instead of a full copy.

Comment: 1. `spreading_map` seems to be only read inside the loops. 2. Are you sure `finished` must be declared outside loops? Its usage does not seem right. 3. Did you try `std::thread`?

Comment: @zdf `spreding_map` is written using `current_row_ptr` , `finished` is used by `while` loop ,so it have to be defined before the loop.

Comment: @Laci 1. I may be wrong, as I am on a phone, but `spreading_map` size does not change, only its content changes and this happens in different threads and different rows; a different one for each thread. 2. I still have some doubts regarding `finished`.

Comment: @zdf We agree on that the content of `spreading_map` changes (for me it means that it is not considered as read only, but since I do not know `cv::Mat` class you may be right)

Comment: @Laci i heared your suggestion, change mage_clone from firstprivae to shared, it just faster a little. and changed spreading_map.copyTo(image_clone) to image_clone = spreading_map, but  got different resault, it semms changed data content

Comment: @zdf i am at a loss as to know to use `std::thread`, i thik i need think more

Comment: @lyudun Remove `spreading_map` from `shared` and let us know if it works. It should work since you do not modify the size of it and each thread works on a different row.

Comment: @zdf it worked when removed `spreading_map` from shared, justnot getting faster

Comment: @lyudun 0. You should see a big difference when using threads. If not, maybe the OMP overhead is too large. Run your tests on larger images. 1. Run your tests in Release configuration. 2. If `finished` is written many times it can slow down the algorithm. 3. What value is `proc_num`?

Comment: `volatile` do not ensure atomicity nor consistent accesses in a parallel program. It is not safe to use it even for a boolean. Do not use it. Use *atomic reads/writes* instead. There is a `pragma atomic` in OpenMP for that. There is also `std::atomic` alternatively.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Isn’t `shared` clause enough?

Comment: @zdf AFAIK no, and a flush is needed (either explicit or implicit). A quick check of the specification seems to confirm this (see Section 1.4.4 of the OpenMP 5.2 specification). The reason it is not done automatically is certainly that memory barriers (done by flushes) are expensive on some architecture (especially a full barrier).

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] + input image so that one can experiment with your code?

Comment: Why do you use dynamic schedule?

Comment: Using a `volatile` variable to avoid race condition is almost certainly an error. It may also degrade  performance. I would set this information locally and propagate to the shared variable only at the end of the for loop, perhaps in an atomic.

Comment: Your algorithm seems ok if `set_value = true;` is performed often. If it is performed rarely, your inner loops working on the 3x3 stencil just burn the CPU out all in vain.